# Color formatting of a cell based on entries in two cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I wish to assign color to I2 cell based on the entries in F2 and G2:

I2 is red if both F2 and G2 are empty
I2 is amber if any one out of F2 and G2 is empty
I2 is green if both F2 and G2 are not empty.

Comment: In what language or application ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is referring to Excel:

use cascading formats:

- select I2
- click `Conditional Formatting` -> `manage rules`
- `New rule` -> `Use formula to determine which cells to format`
- put `=not(and(isblank(F1),isblank(G1)))` in the box, click `format` and select green fill. click OK
- `New rule` -> `Use formula to determine which cells to format`
- put `=or(isblank(F1),isblank(G1))` in the box, click `format` and select orange fill. click OK
- `New rule` -> `Use formula to determine which cells to format`
- put `=and(isblank(F1),isblank(G1))` in the box, click `format` and select red fill. click OK
- you should now see all 3 rules, with red on the top. click ok to close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have covered all the possibilities two rules are sufficient. For example, turn I2 green with 'standard' fill (it will be overwritten where appropriate by the Conditional Formatting rules).

Select I2 then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTBLANK(F2:G2)=1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select amber, OK, OK.

Then repeat for red with:

```
 =COUNTBLANK(F2:G2)=2
```

The order in which these rules are applied does not matter.